# How to display review stars above a custom field? Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am having trouble to display the star ratings (or more specifically 0 star ratings) below the product title, but above the taste notes description (which is a custom field). If you view the image below, you can see the stars are being displayed below the taste notes.

[image]

How can I move the star ratings to be below the product title? At the moment Woocommerce only displays star ratings if there is a rating so I had to write some code to display the stars if there is 0 ratings but in doing this, it moved these 0 star ratings to below the tastenotes and not underneath the product title.

Here is the code in my functions.php

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'get_star_rating' );
function get_star_rating()
{
    global $woocommerce, $product;
    $rating_count = $product->get_rating_count();

    if ($rating_count == 0){
   $rating_html  = '</a><a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '#respond"><div class="star-rating"><span style="width:' . (( $rating / 5 ) * 100) . '%"></span></div><span class="woocommerce-review-link"><em>(0)</em></span></a>';
    echo $rating_html;
    }
}
```

Here is the code in archive-product.php where you can see the product-title heading and below that is the taste notes. I am assuming I need to somehow add my code or call on the code above between the product title and taste notes fields.

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );

?>
<header class="woocommerce-products-header">
    <?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) ) : ?>
        <h1 class="woocommerce-products-header__title page-title"><?php // woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>    
<?php the_field('taste_notes'); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The possible solution is by overriding WooCommerce template from your theme

Create new `woocommerce` directory inside your theme directory (if not exists), for WooCommerce compatible theme it should already available.

Create new `single-product` directory inside `your-theme/woocommerce` (if not exists)

Create new file `rating.php` inside `single-product` directory, and place this code

```
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

global $product;

if ( ! wc_review_ratings_enabled() ) {
    return;
}

$rating_count = $product->get_rating_count();
$review_count = $product->get_review_count();
$average      = $product->get_average_rating();

function custom_wc_get_rating_html( $rating, $count = 0 ) {
    $html = '';

    //if ( 0 < $rating ) {
        /* translators: %s: rating */
        $label = sprintf( __( 'Rated %s out of 5', 'woocommerce' ), $rating );
        $html  = '<div class="star-rating" role="img" aria-label="' . esc_attr( $label ) . '">' . wc_get_star_rating_html( $rating, $count ) . '</div>';
    //}

    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_get_rating_html', $html, $rating, $count );
}
?>

    <div class="woocommerce-product-rating">
        <?php echo custom_wc_get_rating_html( $average, $rating_count ); // WPCS: XSS ok. ?>
        <?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?>
            <?php //phpcs:disable ?>
            <a href="#reviews" class="woocommerce-review-link" rel="nofollow">(<?php printf( _n( '%s customer review', '%s customer reviews', $review_count, 'woocommerce' ), '<span class="count">' . esc_html( $review_count ) . '</span>' ); ?>)</a>
            <?php // phpcs:enable ?>
        <?php endif ?>
    </div>
```

The code above I copied from WooCommerce and modify to show zero star rating. I have tested it on WooCommerce's Storefront theme, and it works!

[Show start rating 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfJZb.png)